Auto Update WooCommerce Cart on cart item quantity change
I want to enable an AJAX auto update when user changes the quantity (first hiding "Update cart" button) in WooCommerce cart page.
I followed the steps from this tutorial.
So basically I use this code:
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    let timeout;
    $('.woocommerce').on( 'change', 'input.qty', function(){
        if ( timeout !== undefined ) {
            clearTimeout( timeout );
        }
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); // trigger cart update
        }, 1000 ); // 1 second delay, half a second (500) seems comfortable too
    });
});

I've added the above script like so:
function custom_enqueue_cart_scripts() {
    error_log('custom_enqueue_cart_scripts');
    if (is_cart()) {
        error_log('is_cart()');
        wp_enqueue_script('custom-cart', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-cart.js', array('jquery'), null, true);           

    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_cart_scripts');

However, it only works when I change the quantity for the first time. Any subsequent click is not registered. Why?

This is because your script event needs to be delegated to the document body and not to woocommerce selector class.
I Added "input" event, to handle when user inputs a quantity value
I Reduced the delay from 1000 to 500, to get something more responsive.
So replace your PHP function and your JavaScript file, with
the following :
add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_cart_js_script');
function custom_cart_js_script() {
    if ( ! is_cart() ) return;
    wc_enqueue_js( "var timeout; 
    $(document.body).on('change input', 'input.qty', function(){
        if ( timeout !== undefined ) clearTimeout( timeout );
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $('[name=update_cart]').trigger('click'); // trigger cart update
        }, 500 );
    });" );
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works under Storefront theme.

Similar:

Woocommerce Ajax cart update when state select field is changed
Enable "Update cart" button on quantity change with custom quantity buttons in WooCommerce cart

